# Error in Deploying Spring boot project(Scheduler Project) war on tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I'm getting this error while deploying the spring boot application war on tomcat server:

***Error :*** 
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/smartziStripe.war
Mar 20, 2020 1:15:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/smartziStripe/WEB-INF/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.(ConstantPool.java:55)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:176)

Other details :

**Server :** Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 
**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any suggestion to resolve the problem?

Comment: Looks like wrong java version

Comment: Server java version is - JVM Version:    1.8.0_201-b09.

Comment: looks like gson-2.8.6 needs java 9 https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. Try to use an older version

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure your java version is compatible with Tomcat 8. I believe you can use any Java version 7 or later for tomcat 8

Comment: Server java version is - JVM Version: 1.8.0_201.

Answer (score 0):

Try tomcat version 8.0.46 it should resolve your problem.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Faced same problem